# Protractor - Having trouble returning values from a promise

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I know that my problem is that my promises are not executing in the order that I'm expecting, but I'm new to Protractor and was hoping someone here would be kind enough to please point out my (probably simple) mistake. I have a test that's building two arrays, and I'd like to return those two arrays and then set them locally where I can use them in other tests. Problem is those two array's come back undefined. This is my first post so take it easy on me. If I posted this incorrectly, just let me know, and I'll correct it.

Here's what I get in log:
"Size of Index Array before RETURN: 5
"ARRAY.VALUE1: undefined"
"ARRAY.VALUE2: undefined"

Here's the relevant code:

```
it('Build list of existing downloaded files and parse out index', function(){
        myPage.listExistingFiles(fileArray).then(function(array){
        console.log("ARRAY.VALUE1: " + typeof(array.value1));
        console.log("ARRAY.VALUE2: " + typeof(array.value2));
        indexArray = array.value1;
        existingFiles = array.value2;
    });
 });


 this.listExistingFiles = function(fileArray){
  var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
  var existingFiles = [];
  var indexArray = [];
  glob(fileArray, function (err, files){
    if(err) throw err;
    // Build an array of indexes of existing files
    if(typeof files !== 'undefined' && files.length > 0){
      console.log("Verifying downloads... ");
      files.forEach(function (item, index, array){
        console.log("item: " + item);
        var fileNameArray = item.split(/[-.]/);
        // The index in the file name starts at one, so subtract 1 to get true index
        var fileIndex = (parseInt(fileNameArray[fileNameArray.length - 2]) - 1);
        console.log("fileIndex: " + fileIndex + " type: " + typeof(fileIndex));
        indexArray.push(fileIndex);
        existingFiles.push(item);
      });
    }
    console.log("Size of Index Array before RETURN: " + indexArray.length);
  deferred.fulfill(value1=indexArray, value2=existingFiles);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create an object and attach it in deffered.fullfil:
(Please use this code to reflect logic in your codes)
Here is how you can do it.

angularHomePage.po.js:

```
 var AngularHomepage = function() {
 this.listExistingFiles=function(){
  var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
  var existingFiles = [];
  var indexArray = [];
   indexArray.push('fileIndex1');
    existingFiles.push('item1');
   indexArray.push('fileIndex');
   existingFiles.push('item');
    obj= {
        value1:indexArray,
        value2:indexArray
    }

console.log("Size of Index Array before RETURN: " + indexArray.length);

 deferred.fulfill(obj);
 return deferred.promise;
 }
}
 module.exports = new AngularHomepage()
```

and your in test file:

```
var angularHomepage =require('./../pageobjects/angularHomePage.po.js');
  describe('angularjs homepage',  function() {
   it('should greet the named user', function() {
   angularHomepage.listExistingFiles().then(function(array){
    console.log("ARRAY.VALUE1: " + typeof(array.value1));
    console.log("ARRAY.VALUE2: " + typeof(array.value2));
    indexArray = array.value1;
    existingFiles = array.value2;
    console.log(indexArray)
    });
   });
 });
```

Comment: This is actually pretty much what I was doing. But I tried your code to just be sure and it worked. So I was sitting there scratching my head, asking myself why yours worked and not mine. Well.. syntax is a killer! I left out the curly brackets when I created my obj! I had (value1:indexArray, value2:existingFiles) and what I should have had was ({value1:indexArray, value2:existingFiles}).

Comment: Your answer helped me realize my mistake, so do I mark it as the solution?

Comment: Yes please, appreciate it

Comment: I appreciate you, my friend! Thanks!!